# execute system calls on linux from strace log

Tags: system-calls, strace

Is it possible to execute a sequence of system calls from strace logs.
If so, how ?
This one do something i want to do (i think...) :

```
recvmsg(3, 0x7ffffe502cf0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
read(4, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 2, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
read(4, 0x7ffffe502e70, 16) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\22\0\7\0\32\0 \1H\1\0\0\6\0\0\0 \27\31\0\1\0\0\0\232>\205\2\31\0\v\0"..., 284}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 284
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\34\0\27E\32\0 \1H\1\0\0\233>\205\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 128
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\17\0\36E\32\0 \1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 224
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\222\0\37E\234\0\0\0FC \1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\22\0$E\234\0\0\0+\2\240\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 256
```

etc...

Comment: What is really the end goal?

Comment: this is just an example but sometimes i want to capture what a GUI process execute. (to maybe use in my own scripts)
This specific example is just a capture from lxpanel when i click on "minimize all".

Comment: Good idea.  I used a similar technique to learn about and use the inotify() system call.  I wrote a short C program, named the executable, "inotify", and put it in a script.  It takes a file name and another script name, so when file changes, script runs.  strace is a handy little tool.

Comment: to be honest i expected something simple, like an obvious exec("wmctrl something"); in that case. Is there a way to mimicate actions based on system calls capture ?

Comment: I have to stand by my answer below.  No.  I wish it were Yes.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Even in verbose mode, the strings are incomplete, unless they're very short.  Address pointers will be invalid.

Comment: and if the lines are complete ? how can i call these functions ?

Comment: You can write a C program and call any of these you like, with any data/parameters you like.  A quick Google search for any function name will turn up the required syntax, and usually some nice code snippets that help illustrate what's going on.